# sphinx not able to find sphinx_rtd_theme

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm newbe of Sphinx,

I tried to use html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme' in conf.py

but I get message below when I run "make html" :

> sphinx_rtd_theme is no longer a hard dependency since version 1.4.0. Please install it manually.(pip install sphinx_rtd_theme)

I already installed it with pip install sphinx_rtd_them 
(part of pip list)

> Package                  Version
>
> ---
>
> alabaster                0.7.11 
>   sphinx-rtd-theme         0.4.1 
>   Sphinx                   1.8.1

Also I installed sphinx-doc with brew.

Anybody with same issue??

Another things to know is...My ubuntu PC works perfectly,
 but not works on Macbook pro...

Answer (score 1):

Ok...WTF...I have no idea how it works,
But I ran

> brew remove sphinx-doc

and "make html" worked,

If anyone can answer why and how this happened, please let me know...